# Potree Converter - adding to output folder later - duplicate names issue

Tags: three-js, potree

I use the Potree Converter (Windows application) to bulk convert .LAZ files and generate them into a (shared) output folder.  This works great, as each output file/folder generated is uniquely named.

If I want to convert more .LAZ files in the future and save them to the same output folder, some of the generated output files get allocated the names for files that already exist in the output folder.  I have checked the file sizes of the duplicate files and they are different - indicating they are indeed different files.  I do not want to overwrite any files unless they are the same file (i.e. contain the same data).

The only way around this issue I can see is to convert ALL the .LAZ files again - something that is obviously not practical - considering I have TBs worth of source .LAZ files.

Could someone tell me if it is possible to "add" to the output folder ensuring the latest files generated have names unique to the output folder?

As a very basic example, the shared directory contains the following files:

r.hrc
r.laz
r0.laz

If I want to add to this directory later by converting some latest source data, chances are the above files will be re-created but for the latest source data.

I do not wish to have to store the latest files in a new directory.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a batch file to convert you could just check if your output path exists:

```
SET D="OUTPUTPATH"
if exist %D%\* goto EXISTS

:EXISTS
SET D="NEW_OUTPUTPATH"
```

more information: [batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-to-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script)

The same can be done with [powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/filesystem-provider/test-path-for-filesystem?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Thanks zwnk.  If I understand your post correctly, this batch process checks to see if files exist in the output directory, and if they do then create a new output directory.  This is not my desired action - I would like to add to the output path (I have updated my question with a simple example).

I think I may need to create an output path per source LAZ file.  Probably be better structured than having all the converted files in a single output directory.

Cheers

Comment: did you try the --incremental option? the limitation is that the points have to fit into the bbox of the already existing conversion. otherwise you could always run --overwrite to overwrite the complete output if you want to add new laz files to your input

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the incremental nor the overwrite options as there is just way too much data in the output directory already created.  As a solution and from a management point of view, I will now be creating an output folder per source LAS/LAZ tile.  This way any new source files I receive will be created into their own output directories.  If any require updating then I can use the --overwrite option.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments:

As a solution and from a management point of view, I will now be creating an output folder per source LAS/LAZ tile. This way any new source files I receive will be created into their own output directories. If any require updating then I can use the --overwrite option to recreate the output for the tiles concerned rather than having to recreate all.